# Android Color (setColor in Paint) Needs Negative Integer?

Tags: android

I'm simply trying to paint/draw to the Canvas in Android. However, when I set the color using hex values or using the setARGB method, it doesn't work. But when I use Color.x (eg, Color.GREEN) it works. Here's the code:

```
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    Paint paintBackground = new Paint();
    int green = Color.argb(0, 0, 255, 0); // 65280 (Won't work)
    green = 0x0000ff00; // 65280 (Won't work)
    paintBackground.setARGB(0, 0, 255, 0);
    green = paintBackground.getColor(); // 65280 (Won't work)
    green = Color.GREEN; // -16711936 (Works!)
    paintBackground.setColor(green);
    green = paintBackground.getColor(); // -16711936
    paintBackground.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, paintBackground);
```

So basically Color.GREEN returns -16711936 - and this WORKS.
However, the hex value is 65280 - and this DOES NOT WORK. That is, it doesn't paint the green rectangle.

I need to use hex values because I need to set the color to `0x00ffff00` here and then later to a different hex value.

Does Android Color (setColor in Paint) Need a Negative Integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `0x0000ff00` is not *green*, but fully *transparent green*. Fully *opaque green* would be `0xff00ff00` which is, as you have already noticed, `-16711936`. Similarly, when using `setARGB` you need to specify `255` for alpha for the color to be fully *opaque*.

Comment: Thank you! Total oversight on my part. I was going by sample code in Java AWT and the alpha was set to 0 - so that threw me off. Now I need to figure out why they set the alpha to zero and why that worked for them...

Answer (score 1):

Color holds 4 fields, alpha, red, green and blue. Whenever anything is mostly opaque it is negative. 50.2% *transparent* green is positive (0x7F00FF00/2,130,771,712) and 49.8% *transparent* green is negative (0x8000FF00/-2,147,418,368)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `Color.rgb(0, 255, 0)`. With `rgb()` alpha is by default 255, fully opaque.